# ¿Cómo cambiar el favicon en react js en formato svg?

Tags: html, reactjs

Cómo puedo cambiar el favicon que react js trae por defecto por uno personalizado en formato .svg

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/svg"href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icon.svg"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG favicons aún no son soportados del todo por los exploradores, especialmente [Chrome](https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg), que es el más usado hoy en día.
Tu mejor opción (a menos que fuerces a la gente usar Firefox u Opera), es que uses un png de toda la vida.